# Home or house, which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

> I have been trying to see him at his **house / home**.

I guess, since house is building we must say house, while using the word "home" is not correct there, right?

Comment: Both expressions are correct.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, both work grammatically but it all depends on the intention of meaning.

*House* refers to a building, it's specific and tells the listener/reader exactly what type of building the person lives in. Imagine changing the word house to apartment or castle, and imagine where you'd go to visit them.

*Home* refers to the place where one lives. An apartment or a castle can be home, but neither would be referred to as a house. Since the word 'home' refers to where you live, it can also be extended to larger ideas; this town/city/country is my home.